# dotnet ef core - InitialCreate missing scafolding when re-created

Tags: database, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

Using .net core 2.0 and setting up migrations in our data access project. We ran the:

```
Add-Migration InitalCreate -context mycontext -project mydaproject
```

Which setup the initial create file with the table definitions. I then later deleted the migrations in the project by deleting the files to re-create it with an updated initial definition. But when I run the same command, the InitialCreate migration files are created by the up & down methods are empty with no definitions.

What else needs to be done to re-create it?

Br, Mason

Comment: The database might have those changes so when you remove the migration you need to update the database by rolling back those changes. [Update-Database LastGoodMigration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

Comment: Have you deleted the migration files only or other files too?`

Comment: I was using the wrong context as we had several, ignore.

Comment: Then please delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 the current database state was saved in `__MigrationsHistory` table. In EF Core you have the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` which contains applied migration names and EFCore version. The database state or rather the current model snapshot will be saved in `<yourDbContext>ModelSnapshot.cs` file in `Migrations` directory, instead saving it in database.
That is an advantage for working with a team on same model base that will be extended simultaneously.

To solve your issure you have to delete the model snapshot file beside your migration files too. You could delete the whole Migrations directory. But you have to delete the already created database, otherwise you will get exceptions on executing `Update-Database`, because of already existing columns.

For some further information you could read following: [The Model Snapshot In Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/model-snapshot)